# nodemon is not working in vs code terminal?

Tags: node.js, nodemon

this is error shown , i am trying to run my serever

nodemon .\index.js
nodemon : File C:\Users\ryuga\AppData\Roaming\npm\nodemon.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more
information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?
At line:1 char:1

- anodemon .\index.js
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
  ```

I installed using npm i -g nodemon

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Open PowerShell as administrator and type:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
```

Here I want to notice that this is related to execution policies, so I recommend you to [read more about it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7.3)

p.s. also, you can just delete the file C:\Users\ryuga\AppData\Roaming\npm\nodemon.ps1